# app created with forcereact create doesn't start metro bundler

Tags: mobilesdk, react-native

Following the instruction on the [Trailhead article](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/mobile_sdk_react_native/mobilesdk_reactnative_create_app), i created a react-native app with `forcereact create`. Everything went well but after i run `yarn start` or `npm start`, open xcode and run the simulator, the metro bundler doesn't start properly. I don't see the green dependency graphs loading on the terminal.

Pressing the R for refresh or D to open developer menu gives error

> No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed.
> Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected
> via USB.

The salesforce app running on the simulator started through the xcode doesn't seems to be connected with the metro started with `npm` or `yarn start` on the terminal.

What's the problem?

**Environment**

XCode: v13.0 (13A233)

Simulator: iPhone 11(iOS 15)

React-Native: v0.63.4

react-native-force: v9.1.1

SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS: v9.1.1

OS: macOS Big Sur v11.5.1 Intel processor

Answer (score 0):

just run Ios Project from /Ios folder run yourprojectname.xcworkspace and when xcode start run the application